# How can I get Cycles to work with NIVIDA GeForce GPU in Ubutnu 18.04 LTS?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

I have an older laptop with a NIVIDA GeForce GPU that I would like to use to render with Cycles, and I understand that this is no longer *officially* supported. So, where do I hire the A Team (IE: with little experience in compiling, how specifically do I get the unofficial drivers or whathaveyou)? I have Ubuntu 18.04 LTS installed.

Comment: Where did you get that information about "not officially supported"? You need to install the closed-source NVIDIA drivers, because those are the only ones that support CUDA.

Comment: I believe that is what I have, but when trying to enable GPU computation for Cycles in User Preferences, the GPU does not appear. Just CPU. I do have a program that opens settings for the NIVIDA GeForce card, and upon computer logon the NIVIDA logo is momentarily shown. Best I can get from this site and others, this is because as of somewhere around 2.5 (not remembering clearly), blender stopped supporting the older GeForce GPUs.

Comment: See, and exactly that's why information is important. Nobody but you knows which GPU you have. We don't have magic crystal balls that give us all the answers about the information you won't give us. You might want to edit your question and add _the exact model_ there. Besides - if your GPU isn't supported anymore by Blender, there's actually no way to get it working, except using one of the older builds.

Comment: Okay, hopefully you can see this. After finding out GPUs cost as much as a small barn, the specific model of GPU is GeForce GTX 260M best I can tell. Do you need the UUID?